# vs2010 : give indent/dedent line a hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In VS2010 by `edit/advanced/increase line indent` and `decrease line indent` commands, you can easily control indentation of multiple lines. the problem is that no hotkeys are assigned to them and I can't find some obvious way to give them hotkeys. How can I achieve this? if it isn't possible I'd like to at least have them on my editor context menus instead of some northwest corner.

Comment: [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) <3 (vim binding for VS, personally find it a great tool combination)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the lines where you want to change indentation, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: ah, it was simpler than I thought. I was thinking of something like `Ctrl+[`